# TrustedPickle not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, trusted

On the UsingPickle article on Python Wiki it suggests using TrustedPickle in order to give more protection to Pickle files through looking for authorised signatures and keys.

I downloaded TrustedPickle 0.01 and installed it as instructed by putting the TrustedPickle.py script iin C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages.

However, following the steps in order to use TrustedPickle, the module doesn't work.

I've opened the script and tried running it and it comes up with invalid syntax and it pointing to Line 142 and Column 22. Can someone look at the script and see what's wrong? This script is too far out of my depth to solve myself.

You can download the script here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/trustedpickle/files/trustedpickle/0.01/

I've tried 0.02 and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please don’t post the whole source from other peoples’ projects here, there’s a licensing conflict since any content posted here is automatically CC-Wiki licensed.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Will remember!

Answer (score 0):

The line in question is:

```
x1, Key, y1, y2 = 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
```

The trailing `L` (for "long") is invalid syntax in [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers); it is unnecessary, as Python 3's `int` now covers both `int` and `long` from Python 2.x.

In short, it appears that the library does not support Python 3.x. The following modifications to `trusted_pickle.py`:

- remove all trailing `L`s from numbers;
- remove `import sets` and replace all `sets.Set(` with `set(`;
- replace all `long(` with `int(`;
- replace `import md5` with `import hashlib` and replace `md5.md5(String)` with `hashlib.md5(String.encode())`; and
- replace `raw_input(` with `input(`;

allow the library to `import` in Python 3.x. However, I have not tested that it actually *works* with these changes.

Comment: So do I just remove the `L`? Or will that break the script even more?

Comment: You could remove those `L`s (and any others in the code) but there are other incompatibilities between Python 2.x and 3.x that may affect this. You should contact the library team and see if they plan to support Py3k.

Comment: I don't think they are any time soon, considering 0.02 was released in 2004... I'm guessing I should just avoid this script then. Is there another way to protect an ordinary Pickle like TrustedPickle attempts to do?

Comment: I have added comments to my answer on conversion for Py3k

Comment: I added one more change which is just changing `raw_input` with `input`. I have attempted to follow this [page](http://trustedpickle.sourceforge.net/keygen.html) and got as far down to "Key pair filename base..." but then encounter an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`. Any idea?

Comment: Well, in some attempt to call `obj.write()`, `obj is None` instead of whatever object is expected. Look at where it comes from (e.g. argument values) and find out why!

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the `getpass.getpass()` code. If I created a new .py file with the coding `import get pass` `passwd = getpass.getpass()` and run that it will come with the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\scms-fsv002a\home drives\n.morar\My Documents\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    passwd = getpass.getpass('blah')`

Comment: `File "C:\Python33\lib\getpass.py", line 92, in win_getpass
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\getpass.py", line 114, in fallback_getpass
    stacklevel=2)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 60, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44947/discussion-between-jonrsharpe-and-royalswish)